# I'm trying to remember the title of a book of case histories

Tags: therapy, psychosis

Ages ago, I read a book written by a mental health professional, probably a psychiatrist, and I can't seem to recall the title. I'm hoping someone here can help.

It was a book of case histories. The author referred to Dr. Milton H. Erickson as one of his inspirations, though I don't know that he studied with Erickson.

The story that stands out to me was of a patient who presented with intricate and grandiose delusions of being a space ranger, enforcing inter-galactic law. The patient was the son of a military family living on an island and he was sexually abused by his nanny; he got hold of a series of science fiction books the protagonist of which happened to have the same name as the patient.

You'd think that I could remember the title of a book I've read twice and so thoroughly enjoyed. And Google only gives me references to Buzz Lightyear.